# Matching game (countdown and onclick event in javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to program a matching game for my project. The alert displays every second starting at 2. There is also a problem with the onclick event When I run, keeps on saying cannot set property 'src' of null.

It shows the random pictures if I remove the onclick event and replace it with the function Open().

```js
function Game() {
  function Countdown() {
    var min = 2;
    var sec = 30;

    function tock() {

      var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
      //to make second and min that are < 10 retain 0
      counter.innerHTML = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(min) + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(sec);
      var timerinterval = setTimeout(tock, 1000);

      if (sec > 0) {
        sec--;
      }
      if (sec === 0) {
        if (min != 0) {
          min--;
          sec = 59;
        }
      }

      if (min === 0 && sec === 0) {
        alert("Game Over!");
      }

    }
    tock();
  }

  var pics = [
    "../images/1.jpg", "../images/2.jpg", "../images/3.jpg", "../images/4.jpg", "../images/5.jpg", "../images/6.jpg",
    "../images/7.jpg", "../images/8.jpg", "../images/9.jpg", "../images/10.jpg", "../images/11.jpg", "../images/12.jpg",
  ];
  var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var z;
  var i;

  function Random() {
    pics.sort(function() {
      return 0.5 - Math.random()
    });
    num.sort(function() {
      return 0.5 - Math.random()
    });
    for (i = 0; i < 13; y++) {
      //for( ; z%2 = 0 ; z++)
      for (z = 0; z < 2; z++, i++) {
        if (y < 6) {
          document.getElementById(num[i]).onclick = function() {
            Open();
          };
        }
      }
    }

  }

  function Open() {
    document.getElementById(num[i]).src = pics[y];
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><img id="1" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="2" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="3" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="4" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img id="5" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="6" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="7" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="8" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img id="9" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="10" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="11" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
    <td><img id="12" class="picture" src="../images/Untitled.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where do you start the game? Please fix the snippet I made for you so it is a [mcve] - you can use Lorem Pixel or placeholder images: https://placehold.it/

Comment: Can you provide a JsFiddle.

Comment: @MattWebb - he can click `<>` just like I did and write a snippet right here.

Comment: You can't use multiple incrementors in your for `for (z = 0; z < 2; z++, i++)`